# Spring Cloud Data Flow - Partition Batch Job using Spring Cloud Kubernetes Deployer : Environment properties not getting passed to worker pods

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I modified the dataflow sample app [partitioned-batch-job](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/batch/partitioning/) to deploy it in a kubernetes cluster via the SCDF server that is running in the cluster. I used the dashboard UI to launch this app as a task. Modified the code for the partitionHandler() (DeployerPartitionHandler bean) as shown below. I am facing an issue with the worker pods being launched without the spring datasource properties from the master pod environment. I confirmed the master step environment has the right values for these properties and it is being set in the DeployerPartitionHandler bean as below:

```
        partitionHandler
        .setEnvironmentVariablesProvider(new SimpleEnvironmentVariablesProvider(this.environment));
```

I worked around it for now by passing these as command line arguments as indicated in the code below. Appreciate any inputs on why the environment properties are not available in the worker pods.
Also confirmed that the "spring cloud deployer local" flavor of this app runs on my local machine without this problem via "java -jar target/<app.jar>" .

```
@Bean
public PartitionHandler partitionHandler(TaskLauncher taskLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer,
                                         TaskRepository taskRepository) throws Exception {

    DockerResourceLoader dockerResourceLoader = new DockerResourceLoader();
    Resource resource = dockerResourceLoader.getResource(config.getDockerResourceLocation());
    logger.info("Docker Resource URI: " + config.getDockerResourceLocation());

    DeployerPartitionHandler partitionHandler =
        new DeployerPartitionHandler(taskLauncher, jobExplorer, resource, "workerStep", taskRepository);

    List<String> commandLineArgs = new ArrayList<>(8);
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.profiles.active=worker");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.cloud.task.initialize-enabled=false");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false");

    // Passing these properties in command line as worker tasks are not getting them from the environment
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.141.22.143:3306/scdf?useSSL=false");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.datasource.username=dbuser");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.datasource.password=dbpassword");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");

    partitionHandler
        .setCommandLineArgsProvider(new PassThroughCommandLineArgsProvider(commandLineArgs));
    partitionHandler
        .setEnvironmentVariablesProvider(new SimpleEnvironmentVariablesProvider(this.environment));
    partitionHandler.setMaxWorkers(2);
    partitionHandler.setApplicationName("PartitionedBatchJobTask");

    return partitionHandler;
}
```

Included below is the worker pod configuration YAML that shows SCDF is already passing the datasource properties as command line, but it is still not being used (the datasource defaults to H2 embedded and not MYSQL as the URL property indicates). The properties are bunched up together (as part of the sun.java.command property) if that matters.

```
- --sun.boot.library.path=/opt/openjdk/lib/amd64
- --KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.233.0.1:443
- --sun.java.command=io.spring.PartitionedBatchJobApplication --management.metrics.tags.service=task-application
  --spring.datasource.username=dbuser --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.141.22.143:3306/scdf?useSSL=false
  --spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver --management.metrics.tags.application=partitioned-batch-job-89
  --docker-resource-location=docker:vrajkuma/partitioned-batch-job:2.3.1-SNAPSHOT
  --spring.cloud.task.name=partitioned-batch-job --spring.datasource.password=dbpassword
  --spring.cloud.task.executionid=89
- --sun.cpu.endian=little
- --MY_SCDF_SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SKIPPER_SERVICE_PORT_HTTP=80
```

Comment: I suspect this is somehow related to the note in this section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/current/reference/html/#batch-partitioning: `When passing environment variables to partitions, each partition may be on a different machine with different environment settings`.  Are you sure the nodes on which workers are launched have these environment variables correctly set?

Comment: Hmmm. This should work with only the `PassThroughCommandLineArgsProvider` Did you inspect the pod configuration directly, e.g. `kubectl get pod/... -o yaml`?

Comment: ...since SCDF sets the datasource properties as command line args

Comment: @dturanski, I commented out my code adding the datasource properties explicitly to command line (as indicated in OP) and the worker pods errored out. I then checked the worker pod config and you are right - SCDF is already setting the datasource properties as command line arguments, but the pod was still erroring out due to the database defaulting to H2 (ie. not honoring the mysql datasource url that is passed). The only difference I see is that the command line arguments are bunched up in the YAML output (not sure if that matters). I've added that to the original post for reference.. thanks.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, I assumed that note you referenced talks about not setting env properties that may not be compatible with a target env. In my case, I am not setting any and SCDF is actually passing datasource properties in the command line to worker pods as expected, but it is not getting recognized. I've shown the pod config and what is passed (in the OP). Any thoughts based on that. These attributes are bunched up in the sun.java.command property as shown, and not separately like others. Is that a problem do you know.. thanks.

Comment: @dturanski , any suggestions here. I am basically not seeing any of the spring properties, app properties, deployer properties (like volumes, volumeMounts etc.) being passed to the worker pods. they are available in the master pod. I checked the pod details (-o yaml) to confirm as well. As a workaround, how can I pass the deployer properties (like volumes) to the worker pod (ie. what is the property name I need to set in the command line)

Comment: @Kranthi, looks like you have been trying this same scenario based on your other questions. Any thoughts on the above. thanks